# android force keyboard visible

Tags: android, uikeyboard

My function, run from the onResume() does not cause the keyboard to appear.

Am I doing it wrong?

```
private void showKeyboard() {
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(txtSearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
txtSearch.requestFocus();}
```

Comment: are you sure onResume() is getting called and not something else like onStart()?  Mabye add some toast or print lines and look at logcat?  I have found that this is often my problem with stuff like this.

Comment: @Mike Rather than sprinkling print statements, just read through the activity lifecycle documentation.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle  As you can see, onResume will be called each time the activity comes into focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soft keyboard can be tricky sometimes.  I belive the last line, `txtSearch.requestFocus()` is unnecessary, and could actually be screwing things up.  By telling the keyboard to SHOW_FORCED on txtSearch you are already telling it to have focus.

Comment: Hmm. I tried with that line and with out. It has been a tricky test, I have not been able to successfully show the keyboard via code.

Answer (score 0):

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
may help you.
Note that there are Android devices with hardware-keyboards out there.
e.G. GoogleTV devices often have no touchscreen but a hardware-keyboard.
Some are even emulating the touchscreen.

This is relevant if you are developing in an emulator:

http://plainoldstan.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-set-focus-and-show-soft.html

"When experimenting I was not actually getting what I wanted until I realized I should have an emulator device with no hardware keyboard:"

Comment: I just confirmed that show_forced works but only on real devices with no hardware-keyboard and on emulators where you EXPLICITYLY set that the emulator has no hardware keyboard.