# Softkeyboard not showing in a AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

So i have a menu item that shows `AlertDialog` with a `EditText` in it, the problem is that although it is focused the softkeyboard doesn show until I click on the edittext, anyone got a solution ? I tried

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
                         getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

but it doesn work. Here is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return (applyMenuChoice(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}

private boolean applyMenuChoice(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case SEARCH:
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setMinimumWidth(300);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                        String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        alert.show();       
        return (true);
    case DELETE:
        getListView().setAdapter(null);
        return (true);
    }
    return (false);
}
```

Comment: see this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517704/android-force-keyboard-visible][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517704/android-force-keyboard-visible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code,

**TO OPEN**

```
                 ettext.requestFocus();
                ettext.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        keyboard.showSoftInput(ettext, 0);
                    }
                },200);
```

Answer (score 2):

The below [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30596497/730807) works for me

Just comment the 
`alert.show();`
in your code and embed the below code

```
AlertDialog alertDlg = alert.create();

alertDlg.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

alertDlg.show();
```

**Hard-coded delays** are never recommended because they may introduce *unpredictable behavior under different conditions / different devices*.