# Android Edittext cursor invisible

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext in my application that will show the cursor correctly in Froyo or Gingerbread, however in later sdks the cursor is invisible. I have found online the solution is to set the android:textCursorDrawable="@null" so that the edittext will use the font color for the cursor. However, since my minsdkversion is 8, I do not have access to that property.

Is their either a way to selectively add a property based on the sdk you are on? Or possibly a way to work around this so that I can have visible cursors on both older and newer sdk versions?

Comment: Can't you use different layout folders for the versions above `Gingerbread` where you set that property?

Comment: @Luksprog that's probably the easiest way from what I can see.

Comment: @Luksprog Would you mind posting an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know your current setup, but one way to use that property is to use different layouts folders based on various android versions. `android:textCursorDrawable` is a property introduced in API 12 so you could have a layout folder like `layout-v12` which will be used where the API is 12 or greater. In the layouts from this folder the use of the property is valid.
For lower versions, `Froyo` and `Gingerbread`, you don't have any problems so you would use a default folder, `layout`. In the end you'll have two layouts folder(containing the same layout files):

```
layout // don't need the property
layout-v12 // use the property
```

That leaves out API 11, I don't know if this is a deal breaker for you.

Comment: this doesn't work because eclipse will still complain about the layout-14 layout having an invalid attribute for the minsdk version.

Comment: @timT I don't get that error. Make sure you have the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your targetSdkVersion to API level 13 or higher to gain access to the android:textCursorDrawable property

Answer (score 0):

If you not has a cursor I guess the input is simple and say you only can enter new chars at end of the text?

I think you can use a TextView and to this add you own [KeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener%28android.text.method.KeyListener%29)?
But in this case you will has problem with the virtual keyboard not is show, see some of this links:

[Forcing the Soft Keyboard open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479504/forcing-the-soft-keyboard-open)

[android force keyboard visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517704/android-force-keyboard-visible)

or create you own keyboard if the rang of valid keys is very limit as only digits.