# EditText one in focus others invisible?

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, border

I have a problem with a form.

I have inserted 3 EditText and one is in focus, but others are invisible but we can click on.

What is the problem? Can i set a bottom border for others edittext even if there are not in focus?

Edit :

Here is an image of the problem :

http://hpics.li/2c79ed7

Here is the code of the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/group_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/btnBackground"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Titre du deal"
                            android:textColor="@color/hautLayout"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditText_titre"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1" >

                            <requestFocus />
                        </EditText>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Lien du deal"
                            android:textColor="@color/hautLayout"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditText_lien"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Prix sans réduction"
                            android:textColor="@color/hautLayout"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditText_PrixSansReduc"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1" />

                    </LinearLayout>


        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't provide the layout file, also an image with the 3 `EditTexts` would be nice.

Comment: See if this is what you mean ::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222453/android-edittext-cursor-invisible

Comment: I have edited the post with your requests.